# Two species are competing in a region for control of a limited resource

Tags: statistics

"Two species are competing in a region for control of a limited amount of a certain resource. Let $X$ denote the proportion of the resource controlled by species $1$ and suppose $X$ is distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$. Find the expected amount controlled by the species having majority control."

**ATTEMPT AT SOLUTION**
Since the distribution is uniform, we expect $X=.5$. So neither species is expected to have majority control; thus, the answer should probably be $.5$.

**THE SOLUTION**
If I understand correctly, the solution goes like this: $X$ has a $.5$ chance of being below $.5$ for species $1$, in which case the expected control of species $1$ is $.25$, meaning the expected control of species $2$ is $.75$ (in which case species $2$ controls the majority). On the other hand, $X$ also has a $.5$ chance of being greater than $.5$. In that case, the expected control is $.75$ for species $1$. Finally, we get the expected amount controlled by the species having majority control is $.5*.75+.5*.75=.75$.

I'm confused as to why these solutions differ. To me, it seems like a contradiction, but I know my understanding's probably off somewhere.

Comment: On average the amount controlled by $X$ is indeed $0.5$. But imagine cutting a rod of length $1$ into $2$ parts, with uniform distribution. The length of the larger part will never, or hardly ever, be exactly $0.5$, and often it will be much bigger. So the average size of the larger part should be substantially bigger than $0.5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second answer is correct.  The first is wrong.  The main problem with it is that there's a difference between

1. Picking a particular species and asking about its share,
2. Seeing which species has the majority and **then** asking about its share.